# Painting new boards installed on old front porch

Tags: wood, paint, porch

Hi—I recently replaced a number of rotten boards in my old (50+ years) front porch. Here is what I need to do, and I understand timing is important:

1. Let PT wood from Lowe’s dry out (1 month?)
2. Pressure wash the old boards because they have years and years of dirt and wear
3. Paint the entire porch with a new and beautiful color.

I currently have a striped floor—a mix of old and new wood. Do I go ahead and pressure wash the entire floor now, then sit and wait one month for the new wood to dry out?

Trying to get the order of work just right because I want the perfect front porch—thank you for advice!!

Comment: That seems like a reasonable plan. Did you have a more specific question?

Comment: Lesson I learned from doing step 1 years ago: make sure the PT wood is stacked, and not just laying around. Some boards will tend towards warping without resistance holding it in place.

Answer (score 1):

In my humble opinion, I'd wait for the new wood to dry out and then pressure clean everything. There will be some seepage/residue from the pressure treated wood that you'll want to remove before painting, plus, it will get dirty while drying. Same with the floor, if you pressure clean it now, it will get dirty while the new wood is drying out. After pressure cleaning, wait until both woods are completely dry before painting.

Get your new and beautiful paint now and follow any additional instructions that are included with it.